# How to use a variable from main in another function?

Tags: python

In the following code how to I make the variable 'guesses' available to me in the 'end' function. Whenever I try this I just receive a guesses is not defined. In the play function I am returning a number and if I understand correctly than that number should be equal to 'guesses', and for a reason I don't understand 'guesses' won't work in 'end'.

```
def main():
    guesses = play()
    play_again = again()
    while (play_again == True):
        guesses = play()
        play_again = again()
        total_games = 1
        total_games += 1
    end()


def end():
    print("Results: ")
    print("Total: " + print(str(guesses + 1)))
```

Comment: I think your indentation is mistyped

Comment: Pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass `guesses` as a parameter to `end()`

```
def main():
    guesses = play()
    play_again = again()
    while (play_again == True):
        guesses = play()
        play_again = again()
        total_games = 1
        total_games += 1
    end(guesses)

def end(guesses):
    print("Results: ")
print("Total: " + str(guesses + 1))
```

Or another option(although I don't recommend it unless you know what your doing), is to make guess global in main.

```
guesses = None

def main():
    global guesses
    guesses = play()
    play_again = again()
    while (play_again == True):
        guesses = play()
        play_again = again()
        total_games = 1
        total_games += 1
    end()

def end():
    print("Results: ")
print("Total: " + str(guesses + 1))
```

And to note, i fixed your print statements. You don't need to use print twice to print data you passed into `print()`'s parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Pass it as a parameter

```
def main():
    guesses = play()
    play_again = again()
    while (play_again == True):
        guesses = play()
        play_again = again()
        total_games = 1
        total_games += 1
    end(guesses)

def end(guesses):
    print("Results: ")
    print("Total: " + str(guesses + 1))
```

Passing inputs as parameters, and using `return` to pass variables out as outputs allows you to control the flow of data in your program and not use `global` variables as a crutch.

Comment: Aw shoot! You beat by a few seconds. Nevertheless...+1

Comment: print(print()) is going to have some strange behavior. as in it will not work as desired.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Good catch, I didn't look too carefully at the rest of their code

Comment: I really like Python's ability to return multiple variables at the same time. Going back to C++ always feels like putting on a straight jacket.

Comment: @MarkRansom `return std::make_tuple(...)` :P Although that's going to get way better once C++17 comes out with [structured bindings](https://skebanga.github.io/structured-bindings/)... still not as pretty as Python, but going in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
def main():
    guesses = play()
    play_again = again()
    while (play_again == True):
        guesses = play()
        play_again = again()
        total_games = 1
        total_games += 1
    end(guesses)

def end(guesses):
    print("Results: ")
    print("Total: {}".format(guesses + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`main()` and `end()` are two separate functions with separate scopes. You defined the variable `guesses` inside the function `main()`. It will not be available to `end()`, because the scope in which `end()` was defined did not have access to `guesses`. This is despite the fact that `end()` is called within `main()`. The inside of the function isn't aware that `guesses` exists when `end()` was created/defined.

The need to pass information between two functions as you are trying to do highlights the need for a very common programming paradigm regarding data flow. You can pass information into a function through the use of "parameters" or "arguments". These are variables that are defined or set when a function is called.

In python, they look like this:

```
def function(argument):
    #do something with argument
    print (argument)
```

Comment: Nice explanation! It probably is a good idea to [teach the OP to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). +1